# I can't edit some questions, the edit button is grayed out

Tags: support

There is [THIS](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67776/print-effect-similar-to-tom-haugomat) question and I wanted to edit it to make it clearer and also add the image inline but I can't. The edit button is grayed out. I have seen this once before and I wanted to know why some questions can't be edited.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing it's because there was an edit already pending. It just got approved so take a look to see if you can edit it now (although you shouldn't need to anymore)

Comment: yeah, I already edited that Q, so you'll have to wait your turn :)

Comment: @CAI Yup, I can edit it now but again, there's no need for it :)) Thanks, but shouldn't there be a notification like "You can't edit this question cause another edit is waiting for approval". ?

Comment: @PieBie Well, that's not the problem but I didn't know the reason, shouldn't there be a notification like "You can't edit this question cause another edit is waiting for approval"

Comment: I know for a fact that you get a message when trying to edit a Q you already edited yourself. Don't know if you get a message if an edit from someone else is still pending, but I'd imagine so. You sure you didn't miss it?

Comment: To be honest i thought there was. Not much we can do about it if there isn't. Maybe bring it up on [metase]

Comment: @CAI: Me too. But if it's one of those blue flag type things... they're easily missed.

Comment: @PieBie As you can see in my print-screen, the edit button is grayed out and even if I clicked it I got nothing...

Comment: @PieBie very true.

Comment: Apparantly, the reason is disclosed on hover, as can be read in this [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91172/always-show-the-edit-button-on-questions/138944#138944)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a handful of conditions where we will stop accepting suggested edits:

1. A large number of suggested edits by you were rejected in the past
   week (at least 5 more than one-third of your accepted edits).
2. We are out of empty slots in the queue (currently 20 120 200)
3. There is an edit to a particular post that was not approved yet.
4. You are not logged in and the post is less than 10 minutes old.
5. You are on a child meta.

In the past no "edit" link would be shown at all; since July 2012 the edit link is disabled and the mouse hover tooltip will explain why an edit cannot be suggested, like "Account is not allowed to suggest edits".

See [this meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled/81701#81701) for full info.

Comment: Well, I guess it must be one of the above :) Thank you :)